# Calculating the energy input to a system from a magnetic stir bar

Tags: fluid-dynamics, energy

I would like to figure out the rate of energy input into a beaker of water from stirring the water with a magnetic stir bar. I know this should depend on the rotational rate of the stir bar, and physical dimensions of the bar (because this would change the rate of water being displaced), but I'm not sure if there's a straightforward way to calculate how much energy I'm adding to the system by stirring. I would like to compare various properties of the system when adding energy through stirring vs. raising the temperature, which is why I'd like to calculate the energy added to the system through stirring.

How can I calculate the rate of energy added to a system from a magnetic stir bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be practical depending on your system and the equipment you have a available, but one way to do this is to monitor the deceleration of the bead when the magnetic stirrer is removed.

If you let the system come to equilibrium then rapidly remove the magnetic stirrer (you need to remove it not just turn it off) then the angular deceleration of the bead will be:

$$ \frac{d\omega}{dt} = -\frac{T}{I} $$

where $T$ is the torque on the bead and $I$ is the moment of inertia of the bead. You can calculate the moment of inertia $I$ of the bead from its geometry, or you could measure it using a torsion pendulum. So if you can measure $d\omega/dt$ you can calculate the torque $T$. The power being consumed to turn the bead, and therefore the power being supplied to the water, is then simply:

$$ P = T\omega $$

The simplest way I can think of to measure $d\omega/dt$ would be to video the bead from above, perhaps with a high speed camera, and examine the video frame by frame to measure the angular displacement as a function of time.

Comment: Do I need to remove the stirrer because you're implying that when I turn off the stir plate, it will still be adding energy to the stirrer as it turns off completely?

Comment: When you turn off the stir plate the magnetic rotor inside the plate will stop, but will continue to exert a torque on the bead i.e. the bead will not just be slowing due to viscous losses in the liquid. That's why you need to get the stir plate far eneough away from the bead that the bead no longer feels a significant magnetic force from it.

Answer (score 0):

John, I see how you came to your idea, but you were too quick to assume it is correct. The problem is, that if you let the liquid reach the steady state, it would keep spinning and acting with force on the stirrer bar. The larger the torque of the stirrer bar is, the more slowly it will decelerate, because the water has a good grip on it.
To make it correct, you need to stop the stirrer bar from spinning after reaching the steady state for a really short instance and then observe how it accelerates from zero to another steady state. This would be very difficult to achieve in a correct way, because if you stop the stirring bar for a moment, it immediately disrupts the flow patterns and the steady state if it as high torque.

I would suggest this:
Select a stirrer bar that you suppose has really low torque. Set RPMs, allow the system to reach equilibrium and take out the low torque stirring bar (it will not cause so many disruptions in flow patterns), and remove the magnetic field.
Then drop in the stirrer bar of which you want to measure the torque and then take the video recording of how it accelerates in water with these RPMs. Again, this is not optimal, but at least it is one step closer to the correct result.

I am facing the same problem, I need to assess the power number of a stirrer bar so I can do some scale-down of a big mixer that also uses a magnetic stirrer bar. I think I will spin the water with a top-mounted impeller, then remove it, drop in the magnetic stirrer bar and add in the top-mounted impeller so the RPMs of water do not decrease too much. But then the top-mounted impeller will be blocking the view...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/358836)